# Mule 3.7 Apikit CORS - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: java, cors, mule

Im using Mule 3.7 with APIKit + RAML. Lack of documentation on mule's http response builder, etc.

Http Credentials does not work with Wildcard for Access-Control-Allow-Origin, therefore need to remove the wildcard, and set the value dynamically as the origin in the message header.

error: 
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

How can I set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value as #[message.inboundProperties['origin']]

```
<flow name="api-main">
    <http:listener config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/*" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:response-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        </http:response-builder>
    </http:listener>
    <apikit:router config-ref="api-main-config" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>
    <exception-strategy ref="component-registry-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but not sure I understand what you are asking. You want to override the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin on http request to your API overriding what the client is sending or you want override the header when answering to the client so in the response ?

Comment: Override the header when answering the client so in the response.

Comment: This question should not be specific to mule version, it seems like the question and solution can be applicable to new versions

Answer (score 4):

This issue is more than adding a header to the response headers.

If you are setting the allow credentials header to true, actual Browsers will send a preflight request with OPTION method to "test" and allow origin cross-origin request. Refer to:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Just setting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header will not work.

```
<set-property propertyName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*">
```

Fortunately there is a mule-module to handling CORS request, but it lacks of documentation. You need to set this config at the beginning of your app.xml.

```
<cors:config name="Cors_Configuration" doc:name="Cors Configuration">
    <cors:origins>
        <cors:origin url="http://localhost:8080">
            <cors:methods>
                <cors:method>POST</cors:method>
                <cors:method>DELETE</cors:method>
                <cors:method>PUT</cors:method>
                <cors:method>GET</cors:method>
            </cors:methods>
            <cors:headers>
                <cors:header>content-type</cors:header>
            </cors:headers>
        </cors:origin>
    </cors:origins>
</cors:config>
```

And use it before APIkit router.

```
<http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/api" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
<cors:validate config-ref="Cors_Configuration" publicResource="false" acceptsCredentials="true" doc:name="CORS Validate”/>
<apikit:router config-ref=“apiConfig" doc:name="APIkit Router”/>
```

Note: Actually to you need to manually download mule-cors.xsd definition file, and copy to /resources folder. Append this xmlns and xsi to your app.xml

```
<mule xmlns:cors="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cors"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cors classpath:/mule-cors.xsd" >
```

mule-cors.xsd: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-cors/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/mule-cors.xsd

References: https://github.com/mulesoft/apikit/issues/27

Answer (score 1):

Just use the set property component after the apikit router to add the header in this way.

```
<set-property propertyName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*">
```

The HTTP connector when answering will transform all outbound properties in headers.